# Ubuntu stuck in Emergency Mode

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

My Ubuntu 18.04.1 is stuck in Emergency mode.

My system is running in dual boot mode (windows 10 and Ubuntu). I needed some extra storage so tried adding some unallocated space to my ubuntu installation (sda8). During this process restarted the system and since then system tries to find(sda8) but cannot do it.

Hitting Ctrl + D is not getting me into default boot mode. On running the command journalctl -xb, I get following errors:

**1) Couldn't get size: 0x800000000e**

**2) Timed out waiting for device dev-sda8**

Installation was working fine before I played with the partitions. Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot using startup disk or USB.
Run gparted.
Try to check the partition by it.
If you can not fix the partition, you should format the partition an reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the info.